# where to find cached images on pc?

Tags: image

I try to educate myself about how the internet actually works as a whole. So I started out by trying to understand how browsers load a website. I learnt so far that the very first time I visit a website my browser downloads the images from the server on which the website is hosted. If I refresh the page or visit it again after having closed the tab, to my understanding, the browser this time around draws the image from my computer where the images have been cached. So I thought I should find the images in my windows folder "temporary internet files". I cannot find them there. Please help me understand my thinking mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome stores data on a per profile basis and on windows its usually in a directory like this
"**C:\Users\Window User Name\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile Number\Cache**"
.
The data cannot be seen directly though because Chrome encrypts all local data.